# a problem occur when push a object into a array

Tags: javascript

here's the code

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var entry = {};
var test = [];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   entry.id = arr[i];
   test.push(entry);
}

console.log(test);
```

i wanna output a array with three different object. but now my objects are all the same, why?

[Object { id=3}, Object { id=3}, Object { id=3}]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you're reusing the same object on all of the loop iterations. Create a *new* `entry` object within the loop:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var entry;                      // (modified, don't create here)
var test = [];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   entry = {id: arr[i]};        // (modified, create new one here, with `id` prop)
   test.push(entry);
}

console.log(test);
```

Otherwise, if you just assign to `entry.id` on each loop, you're just changing the `id` property on the same object. When you push an object reference onto an array, you're just pushing a reference, not *copying* the object.

You can, of course, do away with the `entry` variable entirely if you like, but you may want to keep it for clarity, etc. Here's without:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var test = [];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
   test.push({id: arr[i]});
}

console.log(test);
```

---

**Somewhat off-topic**:

That structure creating an object and simultaneously assigning properties to it is called an *object literal*. If you had multiple properties, you'd separate their initializers with commas. E.g.:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
```

is the same as

```
var obj = {};
obj.a = 1;
obj.b = 2;
obj.c = 3;
```

The values (the right-hand side of the `:`) can be expressions just as in an assignment statement. The names (the left-hand side of the `:`) are either literals, as above, or strings:

```
var obj = {"a": 1, 'b': 2, c: 3};
//         ^^^     ^^^     ^---- literal is fine
//          |       +----------- string (with single quotes) also fine
//          +------------------- string (with double quotes) also fine
```

Off-topic side note: If at some point you find yourself using [JSON](http://json.org) for data exchange, the rules are similar but slightly more restrictive (JSON is a subset of object literal notation). Specifically, property names **must** be in **double** quotes, and all string values (even on the right-hand side) must also be in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var test = [];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var entry = {};
    entry.id = arr[i];
    test.push(entry);
}

console.log(test);
```

Try that.