# How to push an object into array in my case?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to push an object into an array.

I have something like

```
  var productCatogory = obj.data; //obj is http request data
  var productStatus   = obj.status;

  var productObj = [productCatogory, productStatus];


  for (var id in currentProducts) {
      if(productObj[0] == id) {                
          productObj[0].push({'id': id, 'name': currentProducts[id]});
      } else {                
          productObj[1].push({'id': id, 'name': currentProducts[id]});
      }
  }
```

My desired result:

```
  productObj = [ productObj[0][{'id': id, 'name': currentProducts[id]}, 
                               {'id': id, 'name': currentProducts[id]}, 
                               {'id': id, 'name': currentProducts[id]}                                      
                              ],
                 prodcutObj[1][{'id': id, 'name': currentProducts[id]}.
                               {'id': id, 'name': currentProducts[id]}, 
                               {'id': id, 'name': currentProducts[id]},                                     
                              ]
  ]
```

The above codes will have undefined is not a function error because `productObj[0]` is not an array. How do I solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please give an example of what you want your variables to hold after this code executes.

Comment: What are the data types of productCatogory and productStatus?

Comment: `productObj[0] === productCategory` and `productObj[1] === productStatus`.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini you can't compare two objects, it just doesn't works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [a problem occur when push a object into a array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546748/a-problem-occur-when-push-a-object-into-a-array)

Comment: Sorry, please see my updated desired results

Comment: Check my update too.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown what are you talking about?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I should ask you that. Your comment was strange.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown `productObj[0] === productCategory` means `true` that both variables reference the same object, and as per the comment in the source code example. None of these are an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`productObj` already is an array of objects. If you want to add/update properties on it, just access the property directly:

```
for (var id in currentProducts) {
    if(productObj[0].id == id) {                
        productObj[0].id = id;
        productObj[0].name = currentProducts[id];
    } else {                
        productObj[1].id = id;
        productObj[1].name = currentProducts[id];
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to *replace* the current object, then you can set the entire object:

```
productObj[0] = {'id': id, 'name': currentProducts[id]};
```

**UPDATE:**

In order to achieve the result you want, you can try to create a property in your objects to hold that new array:

```
productObj[0].objects = [];
productObj[1].objects = [];

for (var id in currentProducts) {
    if(productObj[0] == id) {                
        productObj[0].objects.push({'id': id, 'name': currentProducts[id]});
    } else {                
        productObj[1].objects.push({'id': id, 'name': currentProducts[id]});
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

It works [here in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fsb36sfu/).

Comment: no need to this `productObj[0].id = id;` if they are already equal

Comment: @Khalid I know, I'm just reproducing the OP's code. And I'm not sure if `if(productObj[0].id == id) { ` is really what he want. I suposed that.

Comment: I have error saying TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'objects' of 'New Catogory' +1